# Find an empty array and modify json

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Can you give a hint/guidance on the function call section checkAndFixNullArray. I am checking the input json for any empty array(siblings in this example). If any empty array output json should spit out that array as below:

```
"siblings": [{
  "array": "empty"
}]
```

The rest of the json should be passed as is. Here is the input json (sample)

```
{  
   "request":{  
      "requestTag":{  
         "trigger":"abc",
         "datapoweruser":"german"
      },
      "enduser":{  
         "first":"mansoor",
         "last":"ali",
         "gender":"male",
         "siblings":[],
         "values":[  
            {  
               "ab":"alphabets"
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

output json

```
{  
   "request":{  
      "requestTag":{  
         "trigger":"abc",
         "datapoweruser":"german"
      },
      "enduser":{  
         "first":"mansoor",
         "last":"ali",
         "gender":"male",
         "siblings":[
         {
         "array":"empty"
         }

         ],
         "values":[  
            {  
               "ab":"alphabets"
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

code I tried(works to copy all the json objects to output). I think a small change in the fucntion checkAndFixNullArray will fix this. However I am not sure which check to use to see if the array object is empty

```
var what = Object.prototype.toString;

function walkObj(obj, fn) {
  var wo = what.call(obj);
  if (wo == "[object Object]") {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key){
      fn(obj, key);
      var item = obj[key], w = what.call(item);
      if (w == "[object Object]" || w == "[object Array]") {
        walkObj(item, fn);
      }
    });
  }
  else if (wo == "[object Array]") {
    obj.forEach(function(item, ix) {
      fn(obj, ix);
    });
    obj.forEach(function(item, ix) {
      var w = what.call(item);
      if (w == "[object Object]" || w == "[object Array]") {
        walkObj(item, fn);
      }
    });
  }
}

function checkAndFixNullArray(parent, key) {
  var value = parent[key], w = what.call(value);
  if ((w == "empty[object Array]")) {
    parent[key] = null;
  }
}
walkObj(json, checkAndFixNullArray);
```

Comment: Check the member with (typeof member == "object" && typeof member.length == "number" && member.length == 0)  if all of that is true its an empty array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be pretty simple to do with `JSON.stringify` - just check to see if the value in question is an array and empty, and if so, add the `{ array: empty }` object to it (discarding the serialization):

```js
const input = {  
   "request":{  
      "requestTag":{  
         "trigger":"abc",
         "datapoweruser":"german"
      },
      "enduser":{  
         "first":"mansoor",
         "last":"ali",
         "gender":"male",
         "siblings":[],
         "values":[  
            {  
               "ab":"alphabets"
            }
         ]
      }
   }
};

JSON.stringify(
  input,
  (key, val) => {
    if (Array.isArray(val) && val.length === 0) {
      val.push({ array: "empty" });
    }
    return val
  }
);
console.log(input);
```

Comment: Awesome... This is the easiset way I agree instead of walking the whole object like I did using fuunctin calls.

Answer (score 0):

For in loops are really handy when working with objects.
See below: A lot of different ways to get this done :)

```js
var data = [{  
   "request":{  
      "requestTag":{  
         "trigger":"abc",
         "datapoweruser":"german"
      },
      "enduser":{  
         "first":"mansoor",
         "last":"ali",
         "gender":"male",
         "siblings":[],
         "values":[  
            {  
               "ab":"alphabets"
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}];

for(var item in data) {
    if(!data[item].request.enduser.siblings.length) {
        // Array is empty
        data[item].request.enduser.siblings.push({array: 'empty'});
    }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
```